# How to make reference for ALL cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm trying to find out how to reference **ALL** Sheet1 cells, so made changes would be reflected on Sheet2 cells.

Now I have big data in Sheet1, which I would like to copy to Sheet2. Later on I would have to correct data on Sheet1, so this should be reflected on Sheet2. Because I don't know yet how many cells I will need to fill I would like to reference them ALL. Basically, Sheet2 should mirror Sheet1 with possibility to add more data on Sheet2 that would not be reflected in Sheet1. Sort of 'one way mirror'.

I guess this is not so difficult and someone can give an example or explanation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To setup a **mirror** of all the used cells in *Sheet1* on *Sheet2* use this:

```
Sub AllTheCellsLinked()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Cells
    ady = r(1).Address
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range(ady).Select
    r.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
End Sub
```

This will establish links to all the used cells.

**EDIT**

If you add rows or columns in Sheet1, just re-run the macro.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to do what you want using Dynamic Named Ranges. Basically, the idea is to create a Named Range that is defined using the OFFSET()-formula. This way, whenever new data gets added outside the range, the named range will automatically be adjusted to include the new data.

[Here is one example of how to do this](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the worksheet_Change event.
Right click on the sheet tab and select View Code
[image: Right Click Sheet Tab]

Copy and paste this code there.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Integer

    r = Target.Row
    c = Target.Column

    Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(r, c) = Target


End Sub
```

Now whatever you change on Sheet1 will change on sheet3 with in reason(Copy and Paste will not work for this). The code goes in the Original Sheet. Change the sheet name to change as required.

Comment: It does not reflect already existing data in Sheet1 to Sheet2. Still, by far this solution is best. Could you update answer so all already existing data would be reflected? Or what steps I should make?

Comment: Could you not copy the original sheet before you start using the code.

Comment: I did that. I have copied the original sheet after I applied code and still no visible changes on Sheet2. However, if I double click on any cell in Sheet1, only then data is reflected in Sheet2 (but just text, any colors). I cannot double click on every cell, because to many of them.

Comment: managed to make what I want with Gary's Student code. Thanks anyway!